# module 'tensorflow.core.framework.types_pb2' has no attribute 'SerializedDType'

Tags: python

Does anyone have a solution for this kind of error when I try to import tensorflow:

module 'tensorflow.core.framework.types_pb2' has no attribute 'SerializedDType'

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAc6i.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bg5vW.png)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when I tried to reinstall `tf` from `2.11.0` to `2.7.0`. Trying to fix the issue I uninstalled separately `tf` and `keras` and reinstalled them but it did not help. Finally, I uninstalled both again and additionally **manually** deleted all the folders with `tf` files in `venv\Lib\site-packages` directory. After that I installed `tf` `2.11.0` and now everything works fine. I use pip for all the installation procedures in manually created `venv`, no Anaconda.