# tensorflow.core.framework.types_pb2' has no attribute 'SerializedDType

Tags: tensorflow.js

I have tensorflow installed , I have got attribute error.
when I  debug , I got this error , couldn't be resolved after reinstallation of tensorflow.
please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Possible Dublicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75120015/module-tensorflow-core-framework-types-pb2-has-no-attribute-serializeddtype